# disable browser close button in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing online Exam application using asp.net in this i have to disable the titlebar so that the user has no option to exit with in the time period.So please help with this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good practice to force user to stay on the page if they don't wish to, but you can have some work around if you want to confirm the close event before they leave the browser tab

```
function internalHandler(e) {
    return "Please don't leave the page you can be fail in exams!";
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', internalHandler, true);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', internalHandler);
}
```

If you prevent user to close it any way you don't have control over `ALT + F4` or closes it from Task Manager

you can do it using javascript like this

```
var message = "You have not completed exam. Are you sure you want to leave?";
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
var e = e || window.event;
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
}
return message;
};
```

and you can unload it when user finish the exam

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

or you can create your own browser application using c# windows forms. where you can set this custom option without having close button. You load your web application form in windows forms application easily.

Answer (score 1):

**onbeforeunload & onunload will help you out. You can't disable but you can show user an alert.**

```
var showMsgTimer;
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
    var message = 'Don't Discard';
    showMsgTimer = window.setTimeout(showMessage, 500);  
    evt = evt || window.evt;
    evt.returnValue = message;   
    return message;
}

window.onunload = function () {
    clearTimeout(showMsgTimer);
}

function showMessage() {
    alert("You're Right!");
}
```

If this is not the one you expect. Then please try https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/